# physics.start( noSleep ) doesn't seem to wor

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk, physics

I have the following scene:

[image]

I want to move the ball using gravity so I wrote the following:

```
function onTilt( event )
    deltaDegreesXText.text = "xG: " .. (9.8*event.xGravity)
    deltaDegreesYText.text =  "yG: " .. (-9.8*event.yGravity)
    if(ball.isAwake==true)then
        fallAsleepText.text = "True "
    elseif(ball.isAwake==false)then
        fallAsleepText.text = "False "
    end


    physics.setGravity( ( 9.8 * event.xGravity ), ( -9.8 * event.yGravity ) )
end
```

The problem is that after some seconds the ball object fall sleep and do not move any more. In the begging of the code I have the following:

[image]

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()


system.setIdleTimer( false )

local physics = require "physics"
local physicsData = (require "myphysics").physicsData(1.0)
physics.start( true)
```

Any idea whats going wrong? Why the physics.start( noSleep ) does not work or how I can I stop the ball from falling to sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Mmh that's weird. Have you tried disabling sleeping in the body definitions?

```
body.isSleepingAllowed = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried that and at the begining it didn't work. Finally the problem was that I wrote:

```
ball.isSleepingAllowed = false
physics.addBody (ball, physicsData:get("ball"))
```

but the correct is:

```
physics.addBody (ball, physicsData:get("ball"))
ball.isSleepingAllowed = false
```

I should first add physics to the ball and then `body.isSleepingAllowed = false;` the opposite didn't work.